# Если есть второй уровень меню изменить стиль первого

Tags: jquery, if

Есть меню типа

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Пункт меню 1</li>
<li>Пункт меню 2
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>Подпункт 1</li>
  <li>Подпункт 2</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

У класса ".menu" есть стиль, например, "height:100px;". Нужно сделать, что ЕСЛИ пункт имеет подменю класса ".submenu", стиль общего меню изменился. Например, "height:20px;". 
Буду рад совету!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Сделать можно просто. Ищем сами подменю, потом ищем меню в родителях, добавляем меню класс с измененным стилями

```
$(function(){

    $('.submenu').parents('.menu').addClass('changed-styles');

});
```